# C++ Test Automation using Batch: Specifically how to use Makefile to build .exe for project?

Tags: batch-file, makefile, automated-tests, gnu-make

I'm new to using Makefiles and struggling to build an executable file with file extension of `.exe`.

Currently, this is what I have which fails to build an executable file:

```
output: main.o user.o item.o transaction.o bid.o
    g++ main.o user.o item.o transaction.o bid.o -o output.exe

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

user.o: user.cpp user.h
    g++ -c -std=c++11 user.cpp

item.o: item.cpp item.h
    g++ -c -std=c++11 item.cpp

transaction.o: transaction.cpp transaction.h
    g++ -c -std=c++11 transaction.cpp

bid.o: bid.cpp bid.h
    g++ -c -std=c++11 bid.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o output
```

I want to make a .exe file because I am creating a batch script to do automated testing of my program. When I create a batch script I try the following in my `runTest.bat` file:

```
cd ../../
make
./output current_User_Accounts_File.uaf available_Items_File.ai daily_Transaction_File.tra < Test_Cases/login/login1.in
pause
```

Problem is I would regularly use bash to execute my program by typing `./` followed by the executable. Using batch file it does not recognize `./` which is why I want to try building `.exe` file instead. Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Is there a better strategy to approach this? I have to automate multiple test cases where I take in inputs. When taking the approach of creating .sh scripts instead I run into other conflicts. What are some recommended ways to do automated test scripts for c++?

Comment: Looks like you have a space in your file name which means you need to surround it with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
 g++ main.o user.o item.o transaction.o bid.o -o
```

the -o option expects the name of the output file, in this case the executable. So:

```
 g++ main.o user.o item.o transaction.o bid.o -o something
```

or:

```
 g++ main.o user.o item.o transaction.o bid.o -o something.exe
```

And this is pure GCC/makefile/bash syntax, and nothing particularly to do with the C++ language, so I'm removing that tag.

Comment: Hi sorry I realized I wasn't clear enough in my post. Thanks for responding. That is actually a solution I tried. 

g++ main.o user.o item.o transaction.o bid.o -o output.exe

I would get a message in CMD saying: make: 'output' is up to date. However, when I check the files there is no .exe executable file.

Answer (score 0):

Windows cmd.exe and most windows programs do not automatigically convert the forward-slash to back-slash. Change `./output ...` to `output.exe` and it should work fine. The `.\` would just be redundant anyway.

Comment: My makefile wasn't producing a .exe file to begin with. Thanks for responding. I ended up switching to Linux environment due to time constraint and I am running .sh scripts instead with no issues anymore